# Using springfox to document REST and include exception information

Tags: java, swagger-2.0, spring-rest, springfox

I am using springfox to document my REST apis. So far everything is great but I need some additional features I don't know how to implement.
My REST apis return a general class to include different types of results and also include information about any exception that can happen. This class is like this:

```
public class GenericResult<T> {
    private T object;
    private MyStatus status;
    private List<MyError> errors;
}
```

`MyStatus` and `MyError` are enums to provide information about REST calls status and exceptions that might be thrown during them.

Now my questions are these:

1) How can I include different types of errors that might occur during api calls? I mean I want to provide information about enum types I might send back such as the following one.

```
 ProcessingError(101, "Something went wrong, read the logs")
```

2) How can I include sample JSON for types like `Map`? Springfox shows the JSON format for types like `Map<String, List<MyUserClass>>` in the form of an empty `Map` (Just `{}` in the JSON format)

Comment: This library handles enum annotations: https://github.com/hoereth/springfox-enum-plugin